# How can I connect geom_segment to geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect a segment from the bottom of the graph until it intersects with the `geom_line` at a given x. I think the best way to do this is with `geom_segment`. How do I programmatically find where `geom_line` will be for a given x? How can I expand this framework to support faceting?

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 150, y = 0, xend = 150, yend = 3.248397), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: In your real-life situation, is there any chance you'll be working with data you're modeling, so you'd have an easier way to predict a y-value for your chosen x-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case this should work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 150, y = 0, xend = 150, yend = min(mtcars[mtcars$hp == 150, "wt" ])), col = "red")
```

If you want it for a `x` that does not exist int the data you would have to interpolate.

[image]
For all available x values and with faceting:

```
library(dplyr)
df <-  mtcars %>% select(hp, wt, vs) %>% group_by(hp, vs) %>% summarise(min_wt = min(wt))
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment( aes(x = hp, y = 0, xend = hp, yend = min_wt),data = df, col = "red") +  
  facet_grid(vs ~ .)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 150, ####
                   y = 0, xend = 150, yend = 3.248397), col = "red")
```

[image]

```
data("mtcars")
# View(mtcars)
yy <- mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::filter(hp == 150) %>% 
  dplyr::select(hp, wt)
# length(yy$wt)
```

Since there are two values of interest, it may be interesting to use segment and curve for representation.

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 150, y = 0, xend = 150, yend = min(yy$wt)), col = "red") + 
  geom_curve(aes(x = 150, y = 0, xend = 150, yend = max(yy$wt)), 
                 curvature = -0.2, col = "blue",
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc")))
```

[image]